# JQuery each() not working the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I need some help with the following:

I'm making a jQuery script to animate a menu. This is what I need; when I click the menu button the menu item appears and slides to the side, and on exit the menu do the opposite. I tried using each() to slide on by one, the first click it works fine, but the second one (the exit click) it doesn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
/* Menu Hamburguer Toggle */
 jQuery ('#fechado').click( function() { 
                     jQuery('#aberto').fadeIn(); 
                    jQuery('#fechado').fadeOut(); 
                    /*jQuery('.main-navigation').fadeIn();*/
                    jQuery('.main-navigation').animate({
                            right:"50%",
                            opacity: "show"
                            }, 500       
                            );
                    /* animação menu principal */
                    var delay = 0;
                   jQuery('.menu-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 
                       jQuery(this).delay(delay).animate({
                           left:'+=200'
                       },500);
                       delay += 100;
                 
                    });
    return false;
 }); 
 
 
 
 jQuery ('#aberto').click( function() { 
    jQuery('#aberto').fadeOut(); 
    jQuery('#fechado').fadeIn(); 
    jQuery('.main-navigation').animate({
                            left:"0%",
                            opacity: "hide"
                            }, 500       
                            ); 
                    /* animação menu principal */
                    var delay = 0;
                   jQuery('.menu-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 
                       jQuery(this).delay(delay).animate({
                           right:'+=200'
                       },500);
                       delay += 100;
                       
                    });  
                    return false;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal and verifiable code example

Comment: We need your html code aswell, please update your question including it

Comment: HTML is a navigation menu of wordpress is not easy to copy it to here...
how may i give more information?

Comment: Basically the script works fine the problem is here:

                    /* animação menu principal */
                    var delay = 0;
                   jQuery('.menu-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 
                       jQuery(this).delay(delay).animate({
                           right:'+=200'
                       },500);
                       delay += 100;
                       
                    });  
                    return false;

Comment: for some reason it only works in one of the jquery click event

Comment: try left: '-=200' for the second one instead of righ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jquery animate is defining 'left' and 'right' on the inline-css which may be causing a conflict. Instead, try:

```
 var delay = 0;
 jQuery('.menu-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 
    jQuery(this).delay(delay).animate({
        left:'-=200'
         },500);
    delay += 100;
  });
```

so you are only adjusting the 'left' attribute.

For slightly more robust jquery you ocan also consider using:

```
 //    var delay = 0;     - this line no longer needed
 jQuery('.menu-item:lt(16)').each(function(i){    // using i as a counter
    jQuery(this).stop(true, false).delay((i + 1) * 100).animate({
        left:'-=200'
         },500);
  //  delay += 100;   - this line no longer necessary 
  });
```

here we are multiplying the 'i' counter by 100 to get the time increments, no need to set another variable (delay). We are also using `stop(true,false)` to interrupt any active animation on the div. this should give a much more responsive experience for the user if they click between buttons whilst it's still animating from a previous click.